# When does Element.getClientRects() return a collection of multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, dom

Each time when I call `Element.getClientRects()`, it returns a collection of only one `DOMRect` object.

When does `Element.getClientRects()` return a collection of multiple `DOMRect` objects?

```js
function handleClick() {
  console.log(event.target.getClientRects())
}
```

```html
<ul 
  style="border: 1px solid black;" 
  onclick="handleClick()"
>
    <li>Click the text to see in console</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The *return value* of [`Element.getClientRects()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) method is a collection of `DOMRect` objects, each associated with one `CSS border-box` around an element.

When elements have *multiple* `border-boxes` (like inline-elements), then `Element.getClientRects()` returns multiple `DOMRect` objects. An example:

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let span = document.querySelector('span');

console.log(p.getClientRects().length);
console.log(span.getClientRects().length);
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is a paragraph with
  <span>Span Element having a looooooooooooooooooooooo nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn ggggggggggggggggg text</span>
</p>
```

**Also**, the return value is dependant on the screen resolution. Smaller the size, smaller will be the number of `CSS border-boxes`.

Comment: When I run your code in my environment I get another result. Don't you know the problem?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbKgqz?editors=1011#anon-login

Comment: Also I have noted when you firstly press "Expand snippet" and then Run the result will be different

Comment: @RomanRoman both the results are very simple to explain (I've also added the last line in that reference). The resultant integer denotes the **number of `CSS border boxes` related to an element**. On bigger resolution (like in the [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbKgqz?editors=1011#anon-login) you provided), the number of boxes **decreases** as the element expands upto full width, while on smaller one, the element adjusts its content in multiple lines, hence **increasing** the number of border boxes. I hope it's clear to you now why the results were different on expanding the code snippet..

Comment: thank you very much. It seems that I didn't understand how `Element.getClientRects()` works